# PHP - Detect page url where js embed code is placed

Tags: php

We have an embed code for third-party client's websites, example:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://my-app.com/embed/container/3"></script>`

Behind 'http://my-app.com/embed/container/3' is a PHP script which checks if the container "3" exists and returns some javascript.

We want to be able to detect the URL of pages where the code is placed. Is there any way to do this in PHP? If not, how GA4 or GTM detect the page URL?

I tried to use this:
`$actual_link = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` but it returns "http://my-app.com/embed/container/3" not the URL of page where the script is placed.

Comment: _"Is there any way to do this in PHP?"_ - you could only check the HTTP referrer - and hope that that is set at all, and not manipulated. Not very reliable. _"If not, how GA4 or GTM detect the page URL?"_ - they do that _in_ JavaScript, on the client side.

Comment: @CBroe Indeed, HTTP referrer is not very reliable. So Google do that in JS, on the client side and then use an AJAX request to send these details to their server?!

Comment: Yes. (Since these are basically user action tracker scripts, they are making background request to send data all the time anyway.) Do you actually need the full URL (to be able to identify individual pages) - or would the host name be enough? If the latter, then you instruct the users to add the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute to the script element. In that case, the browser would send an `Origin` header that you can check on. You would have to reject requests without any Origin header then though, because otherwise people will be able to embed the script without the crossorigin attribute.

Comment: Google's URL contains an ?id parameter. Search `gtag` in this page, you will find how GA4 works.